# Install yum on SuSE 11.1 64 bit

Tags: python, linux, yum, suse

I am trying to install pyodbc in order to connect to a database from Linux, however I found that there is no yum installed in the first place. On searching the internet, I found below are the RPMs required in order to install yum, however I am unable to find the right version. I checked this website, http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php, but I could not find the RPM python-sqlite. Could you give me some direction on this. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: SuSE doesn't use `yum` it uses `yast` and `zypper`.

Answer (score 1):

On SUSE systems `zypper` is normally used instead of `yum`.  While `yum` can be used on SUSE systems Zypper should already be available and have the same functionality.  If Zypper will not work could you please post details about why yum is necessary on this SUSE system?

[YaST](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:YaST) is also commonly aused for [software management](https://en.opensuse.org/YaST_Software_Management), adding repos, etc on SUSE systems. It can be accessed through the CLI, TUI, or GUI depending on what you are most comfortable with.

Based on the documentation the easiest way to install pyodbc is probably not using one of those two methods.  These steps should work, here is the [github project for pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbchttp://Based%20on%20the%20documentation%20you%20it%20seems%20like%20the%20easiest%20way%20to%20install%20is%20download%20the%20[pyodbc):

```
zypper in python-devel    
pip install pyodbc
```

seems to work correctly on my openSUSE system, as is suggested by the [documentation](http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/)

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt. Being a DBA with very little knowledge on Linux, I didn't know that I can use zypper. All I am trying to do is install pyodbc to connect to the Teradata database. I will try with zypper and see how it goes.

Comment: Matt - Could you point me to the correct version of pyodbc that I shoudl use for SuSE linux 11.1 64 bit and the dependencies that are required?

Comment: Here is the output I got using zypper

Comment: /home/rbaktha # zypper install pyodbc
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'pyodbc' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Comment: I will take a look, to clarify you are using SLES11SP1 x86_64?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes, it is SLES11SP1 x86_64.

Comment: /home/rbaktha # zypper in python-devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'python-devel' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.

Comment: Looks like zypper does not have that package - Python-devel. I tried to grep the package using zypper packages | grep python-devel and did not find it.

Comment: try `zypper se python` to search for python packages.

Comment: I don't find 'python-devel' in that as well.

Comment: It seems like you may have some repositories that are not configured correctly.  Beyond that it looks like SLES11SP1 was [EOL'd in 2012](http://lwn.net/Articles/517719/).